# Jest with socket.io test passing false positive

Tags: socket.io, jestjs

I am working on a small turn-based multiplayer game project which uses React on the frontend and node.js with socket.io on the backend, all in typescript. At the moment I am working on the logic for creating and joining rooms (something like jackbox.tv) and writing unit tests for a room controller class. In my code a room is just a class which can store multiple socket instances corresponding to an individual user on the frontend. One of the methods on this roomController class returns the number of rooms which have been created. I want to write a test which creates two rooms and then check that this function returns the correct number of rooms.

I setup the server and client sockets in the beforeAll and afterAll hooks and then in my test I am setting up a server side eventListener for "test_event" which will add a new room when received and then from the client I am emitting two of these events and using the callback on the second to make the assertion. I have used async await as I want to make my assertion only once the server has actually received two events. I expect if I were to emit 15 events that there should be 15 new rooms.

Currently the test is passing as a false positive as regardless of the value of `.toEqual()` the test passes. I am not sure if the problem lies in my usage of Jest or if the callback from the socket.io `.emit()` method is not working.

edit: Discovered `expect.assertions(1);` in the Jest documentation. Adding this causes the test to fail and I can see that expect is not running in the callback from the emit method.

```
import { doesNotMatch } from 'assert';
import Jest from 'jest';
import {RoomController} from '../../controllers/roomController';
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const Client = require("socket.io-client");

jest.setTimeout(30000);

describe("The room controller", () => {
    
    const roomController = new RoomController();
    let io: any, serverSocket: any, clientSocket: any; //usage of any here probably not a good use of typescript

    //see example on socket.io testing documentation page
    beforeAll((done) => {
        const httpServer = createServer();
        io = new Server(httpServer);
        httpServer.listen(()=>{
            const port = httpServer.address().port;
            clientSocket = new Client(`http://localhost:${port}`);
            io.on("connection",(socket:any)=>{
                serverSocket = socket;        
            });
            clientSocket.on("connect",done)
        })
    });

    afterAll(()=>{
        io.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    });

    test('should correctly display the number of rooms',async()=>{
        await serverSocket.on("test_event", ()=>{
            roomController.addRoom(serverSocket);
        });
        await clientSocket.emit('test_event');
        await clientSocket.emit('test_event',(response)=>{
            expect(roomController.getRoomCount).toEqual(2);
        });
    });
    
})
```

For reference my room model class:

```
/**
 * @class Model
 *
 * Manages the data of a room.
 */

import {Socket} from 'socket.io';
import randomstring from "randomstring";

export class Room {
    public roomId: string = '';
    public players: Map<string,Socket> = new Map();
    public gameStarted: boolean = false;
    
    constructor(
        callingPlayer:Socket
    ){
        this.addPlayer(callingPlayer);
        this.generateRoomCode();
    }

    private addPlayer(player:Socket){
        this.players.set(player.id,player);
    }

    private generateRoomCode() {
        this.roomId = randomstring.generate({
            length: 6,
            charset: 'alphanumeric'
        });
    }
}
```

My room controller class:

```
import {Room} from '../models/roomModel';
import {Socket} from 'socket.io';

export class RoomController {

    private rooms: Array<Room> = [];

    constructor(){

    }

    public addRoom(callingSocket:Socket){
        const newRoom = new Room(callingSocket);
        this.rooms.push(newRoom);
    }

    public getRoomCount() : number {
        return this.rooms.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is an incorrect usage of the callback parameter on the client emit event. It is necessary to invoke the callback in the server socket .on method like this:

```
test('should correctly display the number of rooms',(done)=>{
        expect.assertions(1);
        serverSocket.on("test_event", (callback)=>{
            roomController.addRoom(serverSocket);
            if(callback){
                callback();
            }
        });
        clientSocket.emit('test_event');
        clientSocket.emit('test_event',(response)=>{
            done();
            expect(roomController.getRoomCount()).toEqual(2);
        });
    });
```